# How do I replace css background url with @html.Sitecore().field("Header Image")

Tags: css

I am using Sitecore 8.2 and I am working with the RenderingModel. I have a template field called "Header Image" that I would like to render on my Layout. Here is the css

```
.microsite-banner{
            background: url(../images/trees_banner_2.jpg)  no-repeat center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: scroll;
            position: relative;

        }
```

Here is my markup:

```
 <div id="banner-nav-container" class="microsite-banner">

          <div class="home-banner-overlay"> </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div style="width: 100%;position:relative;">
```

and here is the code I thought might swap out the css image

```
 <script>


        $('.microsite-banner').css("background", "url(@Html.Sitecore().Field("Header Image")");

    </script>
```

Comment: It seems that the code for swapping the background is not correct. Try to add the new image url to a variable and then use the variable in the css. I assume you are loading a default image. I would recommend to do this in the markup directly instead of css. So, you can check if the image header is blank load the default one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `@Html.Sitecore().Field("Header Image")` will render a full image tag like:

```
<img src="~/media/imageid.ashx" alt="" />
```

For the background image, you need to get the Url of the image. For that you can use the `MediaManager` to generate the media asset url:

```
ImageField backgroundImage = (ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item["Header Image"];
var imageUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem);
```

Now you can use that `imageUrl` to change the background image:

```
<script>
    $('.microsite-banner').css("background", "url(@imageUrl)");
</script>
```

Obviously that is very crude code and really you would want to get all that done in your controller and then populate a property on your view model with the Url, but it gives you a starting point.

Comment: Yes, I get that... the person I am working with is trying to use Sitecore out of the box ... meaning we will need to build a controller to process all of the item's data ... I think he thought we could get away with using the RenderingModel

Comment: Technically that code _would_ work in a view rendering just using the `RenderingModel` - its just not good practice to do so.

Comment: thank you, this worked and I didn't have to use a controller, that is my preference but this is a microsite and the content isn't expected to change in this part of the website, when we build the main site we are going to use more MVC specific components, and glass.